# 'setAttribute' causing UncaughtDOMException with jQuery Dialog?

Tags: javascript

I'm using jQuery and the jQuery UI Dialog module ([here](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_ui_dialog)) to check for new nodes of type "call" every few seconds. Forgive me if I don't know too much about it as I just started using it. Here's what I put in my themes js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        updateModals();
    }, 3000)
});

function updateModals(){
    jQuery.get("/newcalls", function(calls){
     if(calls.length){
        if(jQuery('#dialog').length == 0){
            jQuery('.featured-top').append(jQuery("<div id='dialog'></div>"));
        }
        var call_markup = "<div><h1>New call incoming!</h1><br>Caller:" + calls[0].title + "<br>Phone Number:" + calls[0].field_phonenumber + "<br>Extension:" + calls[0].field_extension_number + "</div>";
        var client_markup = "";
        jQuery.get('/allclients/' + calls[0].field_client_name, function(clients){
            if(clients.length == 1){
                client_markup = "One client found: <br>" + "Name: " + calls[0].field_client_name + "<br><a href='/node/" + clients[0].nid + "'>" + "Click here </a> to view the client page.<br><a href='/clients'> Click here </a> to search for clients.<br>";
            }else if(clients.length > 1){
                client_markup = "List of found clients:<br>";
                clients.forEach(element => {
                    client_markup += "Client Phone Number:" + element.field_phone_number + "<br>Client Email:" + element.field_email + "<a href='/node/" + element.nid + "'>Client Page</a><br>";
                });
                client_markup = "Multiple clients found in database.<a href='/client_registration'> Click here </a> to register a new client.<br><a href='/clients'> Click here </a> to search for clients.<br>";

            }else{
                client_markup = "No clients found in database.<a href='/client_registration'> Click here </a> to register a new client.<br><a href='/clients'> Click here </a> to search for clients.<br>";
            }
            jQuery('#dialog').html(call_markup + client_markup);
            jQuery('#dialog').dialog({
                buttons : {
                    text: "Close",
                    icon: "ui-icon-close", 
                    click: function(){
                        $ (this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            }
            );
        })
     }else{
            //jQuery("#modal").html("");
     }
    });
}
```

Running this however, gives me this error:

> jquery.min.js?v=3.6.0:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '0' is not a valid attribute name.
> at attr (https://28c99794f6ce13.lhrtunnel.link/core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=3.6.0:2:65761)
> at $ (https://28c99794f6ce13.lhrtunnel.link/core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=3.6.0:2:32507)
> at S.fn.init.attr (https://28c99794f6ce13.lhrtunnel.link/core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=3.6.0:2:65332)
> at new S.fn.init (https://28c99794f6ce13.lhrtunnel.link/core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=3.6.0:2:25752)
> at S (https://28c99794f6ce13.lhrtunnel.link/core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=3.6.0:2:1051)
> at String. (https://28c99794f6ce13.lhrtunnel.link/modules/jquery_ui_dialog/jquery.ui/ui/widgets/dialog-min.js?v=1.12.1:4:7059)
> at Function.each (https://28c99794f6ce13.lhrtunnel.link/core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=3.6.0:2:3053)
> at t..._createButtons (https://28c99794f6ce13.lhrtunnel.link/modules/jquery_ui_dialog/jquery.ui/ui/widgets/dialog-min.js?v=1.12.1:4:6736)
> at t..._createButtons (https://28c99794f6ce13.lhrtunnel.link/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/widget-min.js?v=1.13.1:9:1127)
> at t..._createButtonPane (https://28c99794f6ce13.lhrtunnel.link/modules/jquery_ui_dialog/jquery.ui/ui/widgets/dialog-min.js?v=1.12.1:4:6488)

I figure it's being caused by me attempting to target a non-existent div ("#dialog") with jQuery.dialog(), but could someone please give me a second opinion on what the source of the issue is and how I could start fixing it?

Comment: This is really a JS question rather than Drupal, but look at `buttons`. Wrap the object in `[]` and try it again

Answer (score 0):

Clive was correct, wrapping the buttons object in an array solved the problem.